# Testing Checkin policy

Tags: testing, tfs, build, automated-tests

I'm searching for Testing Checkin policy in TFS 2013 but seems disappeared from list. Is it possible? Is there another way to do the same thing in tfs 2013 ?

I need to run a specific test before tfs check-in and avoid check in if test fails.

Thanks in advance
Luca